# excel worksheet ave $ per month

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Hello I have a worksheet with a set of quarterly share dividends from a company and I want to calculate the average monthly amount I receive.

I know that the formula is the sum of the values divided by the no. of months but I want excel to automatically calculate the months using the dates in column D.

The amount of $191 in column O is the average income per month. Is there a way of adding into the formula  to calcuclate the dates from D2 to D9
ie =sum(n4:n8)/12 with the 12 changing to be a formula

Comment: `DATEDIF(startdate,enddate,"m")`

Comment: Hi Scott, just a further query on this formula. Is it possible to set the start date for eg 30/6/2018 in this formula? The formula would read DATEDIF(30/6/2018,enddate,"m")

Comment: put quotes around the date if you are hard coding it: `DATEDIF("30/6/2018",enddate,"m")`

Comment: When I copy and paste a range of cells (these cells have white and other coloured backround colors) into a new area, I get a grey background over the entire pasted area. Why is this? Is it a setting? How do I get the background colours back in the newly pasted area. Please help